# Creating month-day labels in ggplot2 when grouping years for a set of months

Tags: r, ggplot2

Example code is below. What I would like to do is take a series and compare the values of different years over a set of months, September to November. However I've had issues creating the labels because after I format the date into month-day, the column is no longer a date.

For the labels I'd like to do every n number of days, and have them displayed similarly to the second graph, with the month abbreviated and the day given as the number of the month.

```
date = seq(dmy("01-01-2020"), dmy("01-01-2023"), by = "day")
sample = rnorm(length(date), mean = 0, sd = 0.2)
tb <- tibble(date = date, sample = sample)
tb %>%
  filter(month(date) >= 09, month(date) <= 11) %>%
  mutate(year = year(date), day = factor(format(as_date(date), "%m-%d"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = sample, group = factor(year),color = factor(year))) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.75)

### The way I would like the labels to look

tb %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = sample)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2024-01-01"), by="6 months"), date_labels = "%b\n%Y")
```

I've also noticed that the graph changes when I use
`day = factor(format(as_date(date), "%m-%d"))`
instead of
`day = factor(format(as_date(date), "%b-%d"))`

And am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a fake date column with a fixed year:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

date <- seq(dmy("01-01-2020"), dmy("01-01-2023"), by = "day")
sample <- rnorm(length(date), mean = 0, sd = 0.2)
tb <- tibble(date = date, sample = sample)

# Create fake date with fixed year
tb$date1 <- tb$date
year(tb$date1) <- 2020

tb %>%
  filter(month(date) >= 09, month(date) <= 11) %>%
  mutate(year = year(date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = date1, y = sample, group = factor(year),
    color = factor(year)
  )) +
  geom_line(size = 0.75) +
  scale_x_date(
    date_labels = "%b\n%d"
  )
```

[image]